# Confusion with retrieving value in AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I am beginner with Ajax & I am using AJAX to fetch out records. Though I am getting values but my issue is I am printing  table in echo. So if respective record  is not present in database than also its going to fetch null table. And I don't want to fetch table if it is null. 
So for that I used `mysql_num_rows` function.

Eg.

I am retrieving record as 2 echo statement in php file.

```
echo mysql_num_rows();
echo "table.... some code"; to fetch out table.
```

Now on JavaScript page again I want to retrieve only first echo that if it not 0 than only print table, otherwise I don't wish to print blank value table.. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
Send Ajax request ->
  if Ajax request returns "false"
    do nothing
  else
    show table
```

And in your PHP file

```
if num_rows > 0
  output rows
else
  echo "false"
```

---

Here's an example using jQuery

PHP file:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $row['column'] . "<br />";
  }
} else {
  echo "false";
}
?>
```

Ajax request

```
req = $.get('ajax/get.html', function(data) {
  if data !== "false" {
    $('.result').html(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thats what I asked how would I differentiate?

Comment: I described how. Simply check what the ajax request returned, if the exact content of the ajax request is "false" don't do anything with the request.

Comment: I've added a simple example for you.

Comment: If I am retrieving value in table, in both cases my table will surely print if respective values exist in database or not. Thats the issue.

Comment: If you follow the code in my example, the table shouldn't be printed out, as the PHP code checks if there are any rows to be displayed, if there aren't then only the word "false" will be printed out on the PHP page, which the Ajax request checks for, and if the Ajax request returns the word "false" it the request doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

When you are going AJAX call you can do only one `echo`.

You might want to `echo` something like:

```
echo mysql_num_rows().'|'."table.... some code";
```

Then on the javascript side you `split('|')` the data from the server.

EDIT :

Solution 1 Simple solution

PHP side

```
$num_row = mysql_num_rows();
$data = 'Something';

echo $num_row.'|'.$data;
```

Javascript

```
$.post('getThePhpSideData.php', function(data){
    var aData = data.split('|'); // creates an array
    var numrows = aData[0];
    var html  = aData[1]
});
```

Solution 2 JSON solution

PHP side

```
$json = array();
$json['num_row'] = mysql_num_rows();
$json['data']    = 'Something';

echo json_encode($json);
```

Javascript

```
$.post('getThePhpSideData.php', function(data){
    var obj = $.evalJSON(data);
    var numrows = obj.num_row; //where num_row is the array associative key from php
    var html  = obj.data;      //where data is the array associative key from php
});
```

Comment: How can I differentiate in in javascript?

Comment: I added some example hope it helps